# Zimbra - How to change user password by username using SOAP API?

Tags: email, soap, vmware, zimbra

As an admin, I need to set user passwords through SOAP API but I could not find a service addresses my need. The closest service to mine is [SetPassword](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.5.0/api-reference/zimbraAdmin/SetPassword.html) that enables setting passwords through `ZimbraID`. Are there any ways to set passwords **through usernames**? Or how can I retrieve `ZimbraID`s for existing accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only method available. However, you can get the zimbra id using [GetAccount](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.5.0/api-reference/zimbraAdmin/GetAccount.html) and using username.